# Pyspark generate a dataframe column having description of all the month end dates till last year after finding the max date from another column

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a `date` column (integer type). I have to find the max of the `date` and generate a description column having the detail about the dates till previous year.

For example, max date of the column is 20181210 then there should be a column having `text` for the `current quarter`, `previous quarter`, `current year` months, and `previous year` months.

| date | text |
| --- | --- |
| 20180731 | prev quarter |
| 20180831 | prev quarter |
| 20180930 | prev quarter |
| 20181130 | recent year |
| 20181031 | recent year |
| 20180930 | recent year |
| 20180831 | recent year |
| 20180731 | recent year |
| 20180630 | recent year |
| 20180531 | recent year |
| 20180430 | recent year |
| 20180331 | recent year |
| 20180228 | recent year |
| 20180131 | recent year |
| 20171231 | prev year |
| 20171130 | prev year |
| 20171031 | prev year |
| 20170930 | prev year |
| .. | .. |
| .. | .. |

I tried extracting the `year`, `month`, and `day` from `date` column and then placing the if condition.

Any other simpler approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the max date in df and do a cross join with the original dataframe, then using some when expressions to set the description column :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# convert date into date type
df = df.withColumn("date", F.to_date(F.col("date").cast("string"), "yyyyMMdd"))

max_date_df = df.agg(F.max("date").alias("max_date"))

result = df.crossJoin(max_date_df) \
    .withColumn(
    "text",
    F.when(
        F.year("date") < F.year("max_date"),
        F.lit("prev year")
    ).when(
        (F.year("date") == F.year("max_date")) & (F.quarter("date") == F.quarter("max_date") - 1),
        F.lit("prev quarter")
    ).when(
        (F.year("date") == F.year("max_date")) & (F.quarter("date") == F.quarter("max_date")),
        F.lit("current quarter")
    ).otherwise(F.lit("recent year"))
).select("date", "text")

result.show()

#+----------+---------------+
#|      date|           text|
#+----------+---------------+
#|2017-09-30|      prev year|
#|2017-10-31|      prev year|
#|2017-11-30|      prev year|
#|2018-01-31|    recent year|
#|2018-02-28|    recent year|
#|2018-03-31|    recent year|
#|2018-04-30|    recent year|
#|2018-05-31|    recent year|
#|2018-06-30|    recent year|
#|2018-07-31|   prev quarter|
#|2018-07-31|   prev quarter|
#|2018-08-31|   prev quarter|
#|2018-08-31|   prev quarter|
#|2018-09-30|   prev quarter|
#|2018-09-30|   prev quarter|
#|2018-09-30|   prev quarter|
#|2018-10-31|current quarter|
#|2018-10-31|current quarter|
#|2018-11-30|current quarter|
#|2018-11-30|current quarter|
#+----------+---------------+
```